# Refresh View and Data everytime app opens

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a `TableView` that needs to be **refreshed every time the app opens**, but I can't get it to do that.

The reason for this, is that there is **new data for every day** stored in a `JSON` file, so the app needs to refresh to find out if its a new day so it can load the new data.

I tried moving my code from `viewDidLoad` to `viewWillAppear` thinking that would do the trick, but it didn't.

Any ideas?

```
ViewController.m

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    // Get current date, remove year from current date
    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
    NSString *dateToday = [formatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
    NSString *dateTodayShort = [dateToday substringToIndex:[dateToday length] -6];

    // Get JSON file path
    NSString *JSONFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Days" ofType:@"json"];
    NSData *JSONData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:JSONFilePath];
    NSDictionary *JSONDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:JSONData options:kNilOptions error:nil];
    days = JSONDictionary[@"days"];

    // Iterate thru JSON to find Data for Today
    NSObject *todayJson;
    for (NSObject *object in days) {
        NSString *dateObject = [object valueForKey:@"day"];
        if ([dateObject isEqualToString:dateTodayShort]) {
            todayJson = object;
            NSString *textToday = [todayJson valueForKey:@"text"];
            NSString *backgroundImageToday = [todayJson valueForKey:@"backgroundImage"];
            textGlobal = textToday;
            backgroundImageGlobal = backgroundImageToday;
        }
    }
    // Other set up code...
}
```

Comment: Where did you do `[yourTableView reloadData];`?

Comment: Sidenotes:  `[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init]` should be cached in a property, it's expensive, same for the decoded JSON, also look up `dateFormat` for the `NSDateFormatter `. Using `substringToIndex ` is just asking for trouble

Comment: @SRMR do you have more questions or did my answer solve the issue?

Comment: @Larme I actually don't have `[yourTableView reloadData];` anywhere.  Is not having that at the end of my `viewWillAppear` the only problem, or do I need to also create a observer too?  Thanks!

Comment: @toto so I should make `*formatter` into `@property (nonatomic) NSDateFormatter *formatter;`?  And for the "decoded" JSON are you referring to `days`?  I will look up `substringToIndex` because I'm not aware of that problem I guess.  Thanks!

Comment: @toto so I added `@property (nonatomic) NSDateFormatter *globalFormatter;` to replace `NSDateFormatter *formatter`,and `@property (nonatomic) NSDictionary *globalDictionary;` to replace `NSDictionary *JSONDictionary`, is that what you were talking about?  And on the `substringToIndex` part, I'm having a hard time figuring out exactly the problem your referring to, can you show me a link or explain a bit more?  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a similar issue recently, my misunderstanding was that `viewWillAppear` / `viewDidAppear` would be called whenever the app opens (and the corresponding view controller is shown). That is in fact no the case!

How you do this is by adding an *observer* for a `NSNotification` like so:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(updateData) name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification object:nil];
```

iOS sends a system `NSNotification` when your app is launched. The name of the notification is held in the constant `UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification`. You can add your `UITableViewController` that holds the data (or any other class for that matter) as an observer for that notification and perform the update whenever the notification is received.

Comment: I think that makes sense.  Does that line go in the `ViewController` somewhere then?  And do I need to create some function `-(void)updateData` somewhere?  Also, do I need to reload the `tableView`?  Thanks!

Comment: 1. yes, adding the obserer here can probably best be done by putitng that code into your view controller. 2. `updateData` was just an example name to indicate that this is your point of access control from where you can perform custom actions, so you'll indeed want to create a method that is responsible for updating your content 3. finally, when you are done loading the data, you indeed need to call `[self.tableView reloadData];` in order to actually display the newly arrived data

Comment: 1.  Would I add the observer in `viewDidLoad` or `viewWillAppear` or something else?  2.In the `updateData` how much of what I have in `viewWillAppear` should go in there?  All of it?  And should I completely remove `viewWillAppear` and just call the `updateData` method in `viewDidLoad`?  3.  Should I put `[self.tableView reloadData];` in `updateData` or at the end of `viewDidLoad` or `viewWillAppear`?

Comment: you probably need to put all of your code from `viewWillAppear` into `updateData` indeed. and then, you don't call `updateData` directly, so no need to put it into `viewDidLoad`. just put the `addObserver` line from my answer into `viewDidLoad`. that way you make sure, that every time your app is launched `updateData` is called. if you want to know why, you can read more about `NSNotification` here :) https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotificationCenter_Class/index.html

Comment: Sweet, I'm gonna give it a try and let you know!!